# How to convert absolute path in relative path using LUA?

Tags: lua, path, relative-path

I have two absolute file path (`A` and `B`). I want to convert `A` in relative path of `B`. How can i do it using Lua script?

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you provided examples of `A` and `B` and the output you want.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a specific function to do this, or are you asking for an algorithm for achieving it in Lua?

Answer (score 5):

An algorithm to do this would be:

1. Convert both paths to a canonical form. (I.e. starting at the filesystem root, no trailing slashes, no double slashes, etc.)
2. From both paths, remove their common prefix. (E.g. go from `A="/a/b/c/d.txt" B="/a/b/e/f.txt"` to `A="c/d.txt" B="e/f.txt"`)
3. Split the remaining paths by the path separator. (So you'll end up with `A={"c", "d.txt"} B={"e", "f.txt"}`
4. If the original path `B` points to a regular file, remove the last element of `B`. If it points to a directory, leave it as is. (For our example, you'd get `B={"e"}`)
5. For every item left in B, insert a `..` at the beginning of `A`. (Resulting with `A={"..", "c", "d.txt"}`)
6. Join the contents of `A` using the path separator to get the final result: `"../c/d.txt"`

Here is a **very rough** implementation that works with no libraries. It doesn't handle any edge cases like `from` and `to` being the same, or one being a prefix of the other. (By this I mean the function **will certainly break** in those cases because `mismatch` will be equal to `0`.) This is mainly because I'm lazy; also because the code is already getting a little long and this would harm readability even more.

```
-- to and from have to be in a canonical absolute form at 
-- this point
to = "/a/b/c/d.txt"
from = "/a/b/e/f.txt"

min_len = math.min(to:len(), from:len())
mismatch = 0
print(min_len)

for i = 1, min_len do
    if to:sub(i, i) ~= from:sub(i, i) then
        mismatch = i
        break
    end
end

-- handle edge cases here

-- the parts of `a` and `b` that differ
to_diff = to:sub(mismatch)
from_diff = from:sub(mismatch)

from_file = io.open(from)
from_is_dir = false
if (from_file) then
    -- check if `from` is a directory
    result, err_msg, err_no = from_file:read(0)
    if (err_no == 21) then -- EISDIR - `from` is a directory

end

result = ""
for slash in from_diff:gmatch("/") do
    result = result .. "../"
end
if from_is_dir then
    result = result .. "../"
end
result = result .. to_diff

print(result) --> ../c/d.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `pl.path.relpath` from the Penlight library ([doc](http://stevedonovan.github.com/Penlight/api/modules/pl.path.html#relpath) / [source](https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight/blob/b121e7a461688ffb16616231804de5e7df5c1b8f/lua/pl/path.lua#L300)).

Comment: Using an existing implementation is a great idea, but it seems that library depends on [`lfs`](http://keplerproject.github.com/luafilesystem/), which is a binary extension. This might or might not be a problem - not sure how fiddly or not deploying native extensions with their app is - for the OP.

Comment: Yes, LFS is a frequent requirement but I should have precised it, thanks for doing it ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's not for general Lua users, but for neovim users, there is a useful [plenary.nvim](https://github.com/nvim-lua/plenary.nvim/blob/master/lua/plenary/path.lua) utility for this:

```lua
local Path = require "plenary.path"
local abspath = "/a/b/c"
local cwd = "/a/"
    
local relpath = Path:new(abspath):make_relative(cwd)
relpath  -- "b/c"
```